IoTHubDeviceClient_CreateFromDeviceAuth() using symmetric key attestation
I am using the Azure IoT C SDK on Debian. I provision devices on my IoT Hub via a symmetric key enrolment group from my code. Provisioning works fine and I can see my devices on the hub.
The problem I have is that I can't create a device handle for any device in my code using the function IoTHubDeviceClient_CreateFromDeviceAuth(). From studying the documentation, my code must be linked against the library built from the custom_hsm_example.
I've modified the custom_hsm_example as follows, removing any certificate-related stuff. For the SYMMETRIC_KEY, i'm putting the symmetric primary key copied from the portal, and REGISTRATION_NAME is the name of my enrolment group ( i'm not sure if this is correct ):
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "hsm_client_data.h"

// This sample is provided for sample only.  Please do not use this in production
// For more information please see the devdoc using_custom_hsm.md
//static const char* const COMMON_NAME = "custom-hsm-example";
//static const char* const CERTIFICATE = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----""\n"
//"BASE64 Encoded certificate Here""\n"
//"-----END CERTIFICATE-----";
//static const char* const PRIVATE_KEY = "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----""\n"
//"BASE64 Encoded certificate Here""\n"
//"-----END PRIVATE KEY-----";

// Provided for sample only
static const char* const SYMMETRIC_KEY = "FdN/YUSebXlTmhx3KnY90DrgWgEBXhbtE62xyPcvixw8P19oWtD65jXmb6x+WT0aW9blRNo0U1svkoWziKsb+w==";
static const char* const REGISTRATION_NAME = "symm-device-group";

// Provided for sample only, canned values
//static const unsigned char EK[] = { 0x45, 0x6e, 0x64, 0x6f, 0x72, 0x73, 0x65, 0x6d, 0x65, 0x6e, 0x74, 0x20, 0x6b, 0x65, 0x79, 0x0d, 0x0a };
//static const size_t EK_LEN = sizeof(EK)/sizeof(EK[0]);
//static const unsigned char SRK[] = { 0x53, 0x74, 0x6f, 0x72, 0x65, 0x20, 0x72, 0x6f, 0x6f, 0x74, 0x20, 0x6b, 0x65, 0x79, 0x0d, 0x0a };
//static const size_t SRK_LEN = sizeof(SRK) / sizeof(SRK[0]);
//static const unsigned char ENCRYPTED_DATA[] = { 0x45, 0x6e, 0x63, 0x72, 0x79, 0x70, 0x74, 0x65, 0x64, 0x20, 0x64, 0x61, 0x74, 0x61, 0x0d, 0x0a };

typedef struct CUSTOM_HSM_SAMPLE_INFO_TAG
{
    const char* certificate;
    const char* common_name;
    const char* key;
    const unsigned char* endorsement_key;
    size_t ek_length;
    const unsigned char* storage_root_key;
    size_t srk_len;
    const char* symm_key;
    const char* registration_name;
} CUSTOM_HSM_SAMPLE_INFO;

int hsm_client_x509_init(void)
{
    return 0;
}

void hsm_client_x509_deinit(void)
{
}

int hsm_client_tpm_init(void)
{
    return 0;
}

void hsm_client_tpm_deinit(void)
{
}

HSM_CLIENT_HANDLE custom_hsm_create(void)
{
    HSM_CLIENT_HANDLE result;
    CUSTOM_HSM_SAMPLE_INFO* hsm_info = malloc(sizeof(CUSTOM_HSM_SAMPLE_INFO));
    if (hsm_info == NULL)
    {
        (void)printf("Failed allocating hsm info\r\n");
        result = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        // TODO: initialize any variables here
        hsm_info->certificate = NULL;
        hsm_info->key = NULL;
        hsm_info->common_name = NULL;
        hsm_info->endorsement_key = NULL;
        hsm_info->ek_length = 0;
        hsm_info->storage_root_key = NULL;
        hsm_info->srk_len = 0;
        hsm_info->symm_key = SYMMETRIC_KEY;
        hsm_info->registration_name = REGISTRATION_NAME;
        result = hsm_info;
    }
    return result;
}

void custom_hsm_destroy(HSM_CLIENT_HANDLE handle)
{
    if (handle != NULL)
    {
        CUSTOM_HSM_SAMPLE_INFO* hsm_info = (CUSTOM_HSM_SAMPLE_INFO*)handle;
        // Free anything that has been allocated in this module
        free(hsm_info);
    }
}

char* custom_hsm_symm_key(HSM_CLIENT_HANDLE handle)
{
    char* result;
    if (handle == NULL)
    {
        (void)printf("Invalid handle value specified\r\n");
        result = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        // TODO: Malloc the symmetric key for the iothub
        // The SDK will call free() this value
        CUSTOM_HSM_SAMPLE_INFO* hsm_info = (CUSTOM_HSM_SAMPLE_INFO*)handle;
        size_t len = strlen(hsm_info->symm_key);
        if ((result = (char*)malloc(len + 1)) == NULL)
        {
            (void)printf("Failure allocating certificate\r\n");
            result = NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            strcpy(result, hsm_info->symm_key);
        }
    }
    return result;
}

char* custom_hsm_get_registration_name(HSM_CLIENT_HANDLE handle)
{
    char* result;
    if (handle == NULL)
    {
        (void)printf("Invalid handle value specified\r\n");
        result = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        // TODO: Malloc the registration name for the iothub
        // The SDK will call free() this value
        CUSTOM_HSM_SAMPLE_INFO* hsm_info = (CUSTOM_HSM_SAMPLE_INFO*)handle;
        size_t len = strlen(hsm_info->registration_name);
        if ((result = (char*)malloc(len + 1)) == NULL)
        {
            (void)printf("Failure allocating certificate\r\n");
            result = NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            strcpy(result, hsm_info->registration_name);
        }
    }
    return result;
}


static const HSM_CLIENT_KEY_INTERFACE symm_key_interface =
{
    custom_hsm_create,
    custom_hsm_destroy,
    custom_hsm_symm_key,
    custom_hsm_get_registration_name
};


const HSM_CLIENT_KEY_INTERFACE* hsm_client_key_interface(void)
{
    return &symm_key_interface;
}

On calling IoTHubDeviceClient_CreateFromDeviceAuth("test-hub.azure-devices.net", "test-device", protocol) from my application, I get the following failures as below. The provisioning is succesful, but fails on creating the device handle. It's been well over a week now and trying to solve this without success. Could anybody help?
Provisioning API Version: 1.13.0

Registering Device

Provisioning Status: PROV_DEVICE_REG_STATUS_CONNECTED
Provisioning Status: PROV_DEVICE_REG_STATUS_ASSIGNING

Registration Information received from service: test-hub.azure-devices.net, deviceId: test-device
Error: Time:Mon Apr 22 14:44:33 2024 File:/home/azure-iot-sdk-c/provisioning_client/adapters/hsm_client_key.c Func:hsm_client_set_key_info Line:99 Invalid parameter specified handle: 0x55e6ccdeccb0, reg_name: (nil), symm_key: (nil)
Error: Time:Mon Apr 22 14:44:33 2024 File:/home/azure-iot-sdk-c/provisioning_client/src/iothub_auth_client.c Func:iothub_device_auth_create Line:232 Invalid x509 secure device interface was specified
Error: Time:Mon Apr 22 14:44:33 2024 File:/home/azure-iot-sdk-c/iothub_client/src/iothub_client_authorization.c Func:IoTHubClient_Auth_CreateFromDeviceAuth Line:184 Failed allocating IOTHUB_AUTHORIZATION_DATA
Error: Time:Mon Apr 22 14:44:33 2024 File:/home/azure-iot-sdk-c/iothub_client/src/iothub_client_core_ll.c Func:initialize_iothub_client Line:875 Failed create authorization module
Error: Time:Mon Apr 22 14:44:33 2024 File:/home/azure-iot-sdk-c/iothub_client/src/iothub_client_core_ll.c Func:IoTHubClientCore_LL_CreateFromDeviceAuth Line:1324 initialize iothub client
Error: Time:Mon Apr 22 14:44:33 2024 File:/home/azure-iot-sdk-c/iothub_client/src/iothub_client_core.c Func:create_iothub_instance Line:1115 Failure creating iothub handle
Error: Time:Mon Apr 22 14:44:33 2024 File:/home/azure-iot-sdk-c/provisioning_client/adapters/hsm_client_key.c Func:hsm_client_set_key_info Line:99 Invalid parameter specified handle: 0x55e6ccdece70, reg_name: (nil), symm_key: (nil)
Error: Time:Mon Apr 22 14:44:33 2024 File:/home/azure-iot-sdk-c/provisioning_client/src/iothub_auth_client.c Func:iothub_device_auth_create Line:232 Invalid x509 secure device interface was specified
Error: Time:Mon Apr 22 14:44:33 2024 File:/home/azure-iot-sdk-c/iothub_client/src/iothub_client_authorization.c Func:IoTHubClient_Auth_CreateFromDeviceAuth Line:184 Failed allocating IOTHUB_AUTHORIZATION_DATA
Error: Time:Mon Apr 22 14:44:33 2024 File:/home/azure-iot-sdk-c/iothub_client/src/iothub_client_core_ll.c Func:initialize_iothub_client Line:875 Failed create authorization module
Error: Time:Mon Apr 22 14:44:33 2024 File:/home/azure-iot-sdk-c/iothub_client/src/iothub_client_core_ll.c Func:IoTHubClientCore_LL_CreateFromDeviceAuth Line:1324 initialize iothub client
Error: Time:Mon Apr 22 14:44:33 2024 File:/home/azure-iot-sdk-c/iothub_client/src/iothub_client_core.c Func:create_iothub_instance Line:1115 Failure creating iothub handle
test-hub.azure-devices.netPress enter key to exit:


same point                                                    [IoTHubDeviceClient_LL_CreateFromDeviceAuth()] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78340723/i-cant-create-an-iot-hub-device-handle-using-iothubdeviceclient-ll-createfromde) in so?

@Sampath This is not exactly the same. This time linking against custom_hsm as documented, and with different ambiguous errors.
